# Will the stream be terminated?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I have actors, that looks like as follows:

[image]

As you can see on the image, the `ActorStream` is a child of `Actor`.
The question is, when I terminate the `Actor`, will the `ActorStream` also be terminated?

Here is the way, how I create the `ActorStream` in an `Actor`:

```
 def create(fsm: ActorRef[ServerHealth], cancel: Option[Cancellable]): Behavior[ServerHealthStreamer] =
    Behaviors.setup { context =>
      implicit val system = context.system
      implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
      implicit val dispatcher = materializer.executionContext

      val kafkaServer = system
        .settings
        .config
        .getConfig("kafka")
        .getString("servers")

      val sink: Sink[ServerHealth, NotUsed] = ActorSink.actorRefWithAck[ServerHealth, ServerHealthStreamer, Ack](
        ref = context.self,
        onCompleteMessage = Complete,
        onFailureMessage = Fail.apply,
        messageAdapter = Message.apply,
        onInitMessage = Init.apply,
        ackMessage = Ack)

      val cancel = Source.tick(1.seconds, 15.seconds, NotUsed)
        .flatMapConcat(_ => Source.fromFuture(health(kafkaServer)))
        .map {
          case true =>
            KafkaActive
          case false =>
            KafkaInactive
        }
        .to(sink)
        .run()

      Behaviors.receiveMessage {
        case Init(ackTo) =>
          ackTo ! Ack
          Behaviors.same
        case Message(ackTo, msg) =>
          fsm ! msg
          ackTo ! Ack
          create(fsm, Some(cancel))
        case Complete =>
          Behaviors.same
        case Fail(_) =>
          fsm ! KafkaInactive
          Behaviors.same
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case actor termination must terminate stream because under the hood stage actor watching passed actorRef and complete stage if Terminated arrived

I think you can find more information here
https://blog.colinbreck.com/integrating-akka-streams-and-akka-actors-part-ii/

> An extremely important aspect to understand is that the materialized
>   stream is running as a set of actors on the threads of the execution
>   context on which they were allocated. In other words, the stream is
>   running independently from the actor that allocated it. This becomes
>   very important if the stream is long-running, or even infinite, and we
>   want the actor to manage the life-cycle of the stream, such that when
>   the actor stops, the stream is terminated. Expanding on the example
>   above, I will make the stream infinite and use a KillSwitch to manage
>   the life-cycle of the stream.